# SDL2, rotating a triangle about it's origin continuously turns it into a point?

Tags: c++, 2d, sdl-2

How I calculated the rotation: I've calculated the origin of the triangle by averaging the sum of its *x* and *y* coordinates and then subtracting it from the vertices. I rotate the new vertices and add back the origin to get the newly transformed points.

But the problem with this is that if I continue to rotate it about its origin (in a full circle), the size of the triangle slowly decreases and eventually becomes a point on the screen at the origin of the triangle. I want to be able to rotate it without it turning into a point.

```
void sprite::rotate()
{
    rp(x0, y0);//first set of coord. and so on
    rp(x1, y1);
    rp(x2, y2);
}

void sprite::rp(float& x, float& y)
{
    //calculate center of triangle
    float ox = (x0 + x1 + x2) / 3;
    float oy = (y0 + y1 + y2) / 3;
    //subtract center from points
    x -= ox;
    y -= oy;
    //rotate about center
    float prevX = x;
    double angleInRadians = angle * (PI / 180.0);
    x = cos(angleInRadians) * x - sin(angleInRadians) * y;
    y = sin(angleInRadians) * prevX + cos(angleInRadians) * y;
    //add center back
    x += ox;
    y += oy;
}
```

Comment: It might be the case that you accumulate (round-of) errors. To circumvent this, a possible solution could be to keep the original values and accumulate the rotation angle, so that you can apply always the rotation from origin to the current angle.

Comment: @Scheff I'm sorry but I don't understand. Could you please elaborate more?

Comment: When you do `sin()` or `cos()`, the result is most times not accurate. It cannot because floating point numbers don't provide enough values for that. So, in each step you may get a little round-of error. These errors may sum up over time and may cause the effect you describe. Instead, you could increase the rotation angle in each step and compute the overall rotation from original (x, y) to the current angle. Even if there is an accumulated error in that rotation angle it still will result in a proper rotation of (x, y).

Comment: FYI: [Wikipedia: Round-off error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error) and specifically subject [Accumulation of roundoff error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error#Accumulation_of_roundoff_error)